# Tomcat Error, port no in use

Tags: java, tomcat

Several ports (8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I have tried the following:

- killing javaw.exe, cannot find such a process
- running the shutdown.bat in /bin
- i ran netstat -aon in cmd, there was no process shown using 8090,8009

please help me with this problem.

I m thinking of changing the port nos., which if possible and is the right approach, what should i change to.

If not, please provide necessary suggestions

i tried changing the port nos. now i m getting the following error ::Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost.Multiple Contexts have a path of "/WebPro2".

Comment: Change the ports used by tomcat is quite simple, but first, can you run `netstat -aopn | grep 8080`? This way you can be sure you didn't miss the port you are looking for from the list (`-a` shows a pretty huge number of ports). `-p` adds the process name using port 8080. Alternatively, you can run `lsof -i 8080` to see which process is using port 8080!

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `netstat` to check the port `8080`, not `8090`.
2. Run `ps -ef|grep -i tomcat` to find out whether there is a running process of your server.
3. Check `conf/server.xml` in your tomcat home directory if the port number is `8080`.
4. Verify that the environment `$JAVA_HOME` or `$JRE_HOME` and `$CATALINA_HOME` is correct.
   Then try to restart tomcat.

Comment: tomcat admin port is - 8050  http/1.1- 8080   ajp- 8009